# Selecting option by text content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to set a dropdown box to whatever has been passed through a querystring using jquery.

How do I add the selected attribute to an option such that the "TEXT" value is equal to a certain param from the query string?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var cat = $.jqURL.get('category');
        if (cat != null) {
            cat = $.URLDecode(cat);
            var $dd = $('#cbCategory');
            var $options = $('option', $dd);
            $options.each(function() {
                if ($(this).text() == cat)
                    $(this).select(); // This is where my problem is
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var cat = $.jqURL.get('category');
var $dd = $('#cbCategory');
var $options = $('option', $dd);
$options.each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == cat)
    $(this).select(); // This is where my problem is
});
```

With this:

```
$('#cbCategory').val(cat);
```

Calling [`val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val#val) on a select list will automatically select the option with that value, if any.

Comment: am not able to do multiple options select with this approach ?

Comment: This method does not trigger events on $('#cbCategory') element.

Comment: This answer is out of date. As of jQuery 1.4, `.val` will only select options by their text content if they do not have a `value` attribute. Thus in the case where the option elements have value attributes and they do not match their text content, the answer provided here will not work.

Answer (score 35):

I know this question is too old, but still, I think this approach would be cleaner:

```
cat = $.URLDecode(cat);
$('#cbCategory option:contains("' + cat + '")').prop('selected', true);
```

In this case you wont need to go over the entire options with `each()`.
Although by that time `prop()` didn't exist so for older versions of jQuery use `attr()`.

---

UPDATE

You have to be certain when using `contains` because you can find multiple options, in case of the string inside `cat` matches a substring of a different option than the one you intend to match.

Then you should use:

```
cat = $.URLDecode(cat);
$('#cbCategory option').filter(function(index) { 
    return $(this).text() === cat; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 22):

If your `<option>` elements don't have `value` attributes, then you can just use [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
$selectElement.val("text_you're_looking_for")
```

However, if your `<option>` elements have value attributes, or might do in future, then this won't work, because whenever possible `.val` will select an option by its `value` attribute instead of by its text content. There's no built-in jQuery method that will select an option by its text content if the options have `value` attributes, so we'll have to add one ourselves with a simple plugin:

```
/*
  Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16887276/1709587

  Usage instructions:

  Call

      jQuery('#mySelectElement').selectOptionWithText('target_text');

  to select the <option> element from within #mySelectElement whose text content
  is 'target_text' (or do nothing if no such <option> element exists).
*/
jQuery.fn.selectOptionWithText = function selectOptionWithText(targetText) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $selectElement, $options, $targetOption;

        $selectElement = jQuery(this);
        $options = $selectElement.find('option');
        $targetOption = $options.filter(
            function () {return jQuery(this).text() == targetText}
        );

        // We use `.prop` if it's available (which it should be for any jQuery
        // versions above and including 1.6), and fall back on `.attr` (which
        // was used for changing DOM properties in pre-1.6) otherwise.
        if ($targetOption.prop) {
            $targetOption.prop('selected', true);
        } 
        else {
            $targetOption.attr('selected', 'true');
        }
    });
}
```

Just include this plugin somewhere after you add jQuery onto the page, and then do

```
jQuery('#someSelectElement').selectOptionWithText('Some Target Text');
```

to select options.

The plugin method uses [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to pick out only the `option` matching the targetText, and selects it using either `.attr` or `.prop`, depending upon jQuery version (see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for explanation).

Here's a JSFiddle you can use to play with all three answers given to this question, which demonstrates that this one is the only one to reliably work: http://jsfiddle.net/3cLm5/1/