# Using Json how can I select a radio button based on value in my database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hi I have a form that has a button used to prefill my form with data from my database.  Using Json It works fine to populate text inputs but how do I get it to select a radio button based on the value returned from my database?

**FORM**

```
<form action="#">

<select id="dropdown-select" name="dropdown-select">
<option value="">-- Select One --</option>
</select>

<button id="submit-id">Prefill Form</button>

<input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text">
<input id="txt2" name="txt2" type="text">

<input type="radio" id="q1" name="q1" value="4.99" />
<input type="radio" id="q1" name="q1" value="7.99" />

<button id="submit-form" name="Submit-form" type="submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
     $(function(){


        $('#submit-id').on('click', function(e){  // Things to do when 

.......

.done(function(data) {

    data = JSON.parse(data);
$('#txt1').val(data.txt1);
$('#txt2').val(data.txt2);
$('#q1').val(data.q1);

});
        });
     });
</script>
```

**/tst/orders2.php**

```
<?php

    // Create the connection to the database
    $con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


........


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
     echo json_encode($row);
     die(); // assuming there is just one row
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ID because you have same ID of both radio buttons

```
done(function(data) {

  data = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#txt1').val(data.txt1);
  $('#txt2').val(data.txt2);

  // Don't use ID because the name of id is same
  // $('#q1').val(data.q1);
  var $radios = $('input:radio[name=q1]');
  if($radios.is(':checked') === false) {
    $radios.filter('[value='+data.q1+']').prop('checked', true);
  }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently have both radio buttons using the same ID. ID's should be unique.

You can use the [name] attribute to do this, or you can set a class on the element. Here is an example:

```
 $('input[name=q1][value="'+ data.q1 +'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it based on the value of said input:

instead of

```
$('#q1').val(data.q1);
```

Try

```
$('input:radio[value="' + data.q1 + '"]').click();
```

On a side note, you have both radios with the same ID, the results of an id based selector are going to vary from browser to browser because an id should be UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the following link to solve your problem. works fine for me

[JQuery - how to select dropdown item based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743975/jquery-how-to-select-dropdown-based-on-value)

Comment: Except that we're talking about radios