# set a value as selected in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to set a value as "selected" in my edit-form using jquery.
Here's my HTML:

```js
var leaveTypeId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-leaveTypeId');
$('#leave_type_edit option[value = leaveTypeId]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <select name="leave_type" class="select2-container form-control" id="leave_type_edit">
          <option></option>
          <?php foreach ($LeaveTypes as $LeaveTypeNew):?>
          <option value="<?php echo $LeaveTypeNew->id; ?>"><?php echo $LeaveTypeNew->title; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

The select element is initialized with select2 plugin, if that matters.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - how to select dropdown item based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743975/jquery-how-to-select-dropdown-item-based-on-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
$('#leave_type_edit').val(leaveTypeId );
```

it play same as example :

```js
$('#get-id').on('click', function () {
    let value_select = $(this).attr('data-leaveTypeId');
    $('#leave_type_edit').val(value_select);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <select name="leave_type" class="select2-container form-control" id="leave_type_edit">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="get-id" data-leaveTypeId="2">id check</button>
```

Comment: i 've added a example for it . if it doesn't work , you can check again `var leaveTypeId` of you :

Comment: i 've read document of select2 : you must add `.trigger('change')` after it :
`$('#leave_type_edit').val(leaveTypeId ).trigger('change')`

Comment: .trigger('change') worked charm... thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

It wont work because you are not putting it as variable what you actually putted is the string `leaveTypeId` not it's value

Change

```
var leaveTypeId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-leaveTypeId');
$('#leave_type_edit option[value = leaveTypeId]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

to

```
var leaveTypeId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-leaveTypeId');
$('#leave_type_edit option[value='+leaveTypeId+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17933/)

Hope this helps you

Comment: it seems like it is select2 issue... when I removed the initialization, it is working...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('#leave_type_edit').change(function(){

var leaveTypeId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-leaveTypeId');

if($(this).val == leaveTypeId){
$(this).find('option').attr('selected','selected');
}
});
```

**Or:**

```
$('#leave_type_edit').change(function(){
var leaveTypeId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-leaveTypeId');

$(this).find('option[value="'+leaveTypeId+'"]').attr('selected','selected');

});
```

*Without `change` but `onload`:*

```
var leaveTypeId = 2; // for example
$('#leave_type_edit').find('option[value="'+leaveTypeId+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mkuwvfu2/)**

Comment: it seems like it is select2 issue... when I removed the initialization, it is working...