# ajax success , set selected value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-ajax

I have this select

```
  <select id="AttorneyEmpresa" class="form-control">
    <option value="40765167-7972-483f-b34d-6852bb3e7ae8">A</option>
    <option value="EF6620EA-8411-444B-95DE-93C92C864476">B</option>
    <option value="e300eaf7-951e-44ef-9a09-94ce1ab41bea">C</option>
    <option value="22D4ED6E-4AF9-476B-BF04-3B4B84565BDD"D</option>
    <option value="F67E520F-C176-4D6D-B537-04970B82ACE9"E</option>
  </select>
```

I have an ajax call and on success I am trying to set the selected value, using my data.IdSelected, which is a guid

```
success: function (data) {
  // brings the data.SelectedId saved in database
  $("#AttorneyEmpresa select").val(data.IdSelected);
}
```

However it seems the first option the selector is bringing, is the option A always.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You just need `$("#AttorneyEmpresa").val(data.IdSelected);`

Comment: If you go to the console and do `$("#AttorneyEmpresa").length` you will see 1 (meaning the selector has found it)  More than likely `$("#AttorneyEmpresa select").length` will return 0.

Comment: Also make sure the data.IdSelected === the option value and not `{e300eaf7-951e-44ef-9a09-94ce1ab41bea}` or something

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
success: function (data) {
  // brings the data.SelectedId saved in database
  $("#AttorneyEmpresa select").val(data.IdSelected).change();
}
```

[JQuery - how to select dropdown item based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743975/jquery-how-to-select-dropdown-item-based-on-value/35149847#35149847)