# Replace select option text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change the text of one of select option through jquery. But it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/oj3spt0y/8/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var els = $('#coupon-options select').find('option[text="Unknown"]'); // tried .text('sd')
  $.each(els, function(i, v) {
    v.text('sd') // tried $(this).text('sd')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coupon-options">
  <select name="asd" class="form-control" title="" id="gfhfg">
    <option value="1" selected="">Unknown</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="3">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Also  don't use $.each on jQuery objects: `$('#gfhfg').find(".....").each(function() { console.log(this.value) });`

Comment: @mplungjan I got those reps by hacking the SO server. I tried nearly 4 or 5 answers. But none works.

Comment: LOL @Avinash ..........

Comment: Shorter version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644610/295783

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with jQuery's [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) Selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var op = $('#coupon-options select option:contains(Unknown)');
  op.text('sd')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coupon-options">
  <select name="asd" class="form-control" title="" id="gfhfg">
    <option value="1" selected="">Unknown</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="3">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Dupe dupe dupe dupe https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644610/295783

Comment: You may have to filter that if there are more than one text containing the word you have in contains