# jQuery: Setting select list 'selected' based on text, failing strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the following code (with jQuery v1.4.2) to set the 'selected' attribute of a select list based on  its 'text' description rather than its 'value':

```
$("#my-Select option[text=" + myText +"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

This code worked fine, until I noticed one select list on which it failed, depending on the text that was being matched. After some hair-pulling I realized that it was failing only in cases where the text was a single word (no spaces, no non-alpha characters). (All of my previous uses of this code had worked fine with select lists comprised solely of multi-word chemical names.)

For example, within the one select list, it worked fine with:
pharbitic acid
25-D-spirosta-3,5-diene
pogostol (#Pogostemon#)

It failed with:
glucose
adenine

I have tried any way I could think of to surround the text variable with quotes (both single and double) to no avail. (But why should a single word need quotes when a two word phrase does not?)

I have tried hard coding the text in there and had the same result.

This works:

```
$("#constituent option[text=#a#-allocryptopine]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This works:

```
$("#constituent option[text=5-O-methylrisanrinol]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This **did not work**:

```
$("#constituent option[text=adenine]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I tried hard coding quotes. This **did not work**:

```
$("#constituent option[text='glucose']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I could not get hard coded quotes (single or double) to work with *any* text at all.

It's worth noting that quotes are acceptable when using the 'value' attribute. E.g., both of these work fine:

```
$("#constituent option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');

$("#constituent option[value=3]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Below is some code to demonstrate the problem. Two select lists, the first of which is comprised of simple words, the second of two word phrases. When the page loads it tries to set the value of each select list. The jQuery code works for the second list but not the first. (I tried putting a space in 'monkey' to get 'mon key' and it worked!)

A working demo of the code below is [here](http://snubian.com/test/select.html).

I would greatly appreciate any insight into what I am doing wrong here. Or even an alternative selector syntax for using the  'text' attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 

<head>
    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var text1 = 'Monkey';
    $("#mySelect1 option[text=" + text1 + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
        
    var text2 = 'Mushroom pie';
    $("#mySelect2 option[text=" + text2 + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');        
    
  });
    
  </script> 

</head>

<body>

  <select id="mySelect1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Monkey</option>
    <option>Fritter</option>
  </select> 

  <select id="mySelect2">
    <option></option>
    <option>Cream cheese</option>
    <option>Mushroom pie</option>
    <option>French toast</option>
  </select> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply set the selected index of the list? Selecting based on the text value isn't really the best way to do this.

Comment: I get your point, but I don't know the index value at the time. Basically I build a table of data from a database, the user can edit a row by clicking on it and a number of select lists below are filled with the values from the table (this is what I use the code above for). Different values can be selected from one or more lists, then the database and table are updated using $.ajax. The select list index values are id values from the database tables. In theory I could store these invisibly in the table along with the text descriptions but I am trying to cut down on overhead where possible.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

When an `<option>` isn't given a `value=""`, the text becomes its `value`, so you can just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the `<select>` to set by value, like this:

```
var text1 = 'Monkey';
$("#mySelect1").val(text1);

var text2 = 'Mushroom pie';
$("#mySelect2").val(text2);
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RB5wU/), if the example is *not* what you're after and they actually have a value, use the `<option>` element's `.text` property to [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
var text1 = 'Monkey';
$("#mySelect1 option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == text1; 
}).attr('selected', true);

var text2 = 'Mushroom pie';
$("#mySelect2 option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == text2; 
}).attr('selected', true);​
```

[You can test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RB5wU/1/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response. Just what I was after.

(I do in fact have values set in the actual code.)

I'd still be very much interested if anyone has any idea why my original code seemed to fail as it did in particular circumstances...

Comment: @Snubian - was the casing and such correct? The match will be case-sensitive

Comment: I'm positive that the casing was fine, the code was failing only in very specific circumstances as I've tried to describe. And I've tested with hard-coding values as described above. The failure of the "Monkey" example in my test code seems to indicate that this usage fails in certain cases. Running the code on jsFiddle, you can see if you simply put a space in "Mon key", both the text1 variable and in the list option, it suddenly works.

Comment: +1 I needed to match the option value instead of the label text. It is achieved with `return this.val() == text2;`

Comment: Modern readers should note that this answer is out of date; using `.attr('selected', true);` will fail in jQuery 1.9+ and has been deprecated since jQuery 1.6. You should use `.prop('selected', true)` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/496126/1709587

Comment: why you did not give the case [When an <option> is given a value="something"] ?!

Comment: @Stuart Allen: Is it possible you didn't have UNIQUE pairs (value AND text) for the options that failed? I had a problem selecting an option based on its text using ANY of the methods on this page. It turned out the problem was that the value attribute for the option I was trying to select was not unique. So even though I was selecting based on "xyz" as the text of an option, there was ANOTHER option ("uvw") that had the same VALUE as that one. When I made the VALUES unique, I was able to select based on the text (even though the text was always unique!)

Answer (score 27):

```
$("#my-select option:contains(" + myText +")").attr("selected", true);
```

This returns the first option containing your text description.

Comment: this seems not working for the second time. to fix for the second time i used `prop` ie `$("#my-select option:contains(Thrissur)").prop("selected", true);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lj97wus/

Comment: @christopherjohnsonmccandless It may be related to the jQuery version. My post was in 2015.

Answer (score 15):

try this:

```
$("#mySelect1").find("option[text=" + text1 + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function seems to work in your test cases (tested in Firefox).
The selector would look like this:

```
$('#mySelect1 option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === 'Banana';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use:

```
$("#my-Select option[text='" + myText +"']").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

Comment: This seemd to be working and I upvoted, but its not working !!

Answer (score 2):

In case someone google for this, the solutions above didn't work for me so i ended using "pure" javascript

```
document.getElementById("The id of the element").value = "The value"
```

And that would set the value and make the current value selected in the combo box. Tested in firefox.

it was easier than keep googling a solution for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The following works for text entries both with and without spaces:

```
$("#mySelect1").find("option[text=" + text1 + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few of these things until I got one to work in both Firefox and IE. This is what I came up with.

```
$("#my-Select").val($("#my-Select" + " option").filter(function() { return this.text == myText }).val());
```

another way of writing it in a more readable fasion:

```
var valofText = $("#my-Select" + " option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == myText
}).val();
$(ElementID).val(valofText);
```

Pseudocode:

```
$("#my-Select").val( getValOfText( myText ) );
```

Comment: This answer does not seem to differ in any appreciable way from the other answers, including the accepted answer, which is much more succinct.

Comment: This somehow worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by searching the text in options of dropdown list and then by setting selected attribute to true.

This code is run in every environment.

```
 $("#numbers option:contains(" + inputText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setSelectedByText:function(eID,text) {
    var ele=document.getElementById(eID);
    for(var ii=0; ii<ele.length; ii++)
        if(ele.options[ii].text==text) { //Found!
            ele.options[ii].selected=true;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
},
```

Comment: Could you add some text please (not only a code block)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to selected value on drop-down text bases so you should use below changes:
Here below is example and country name is dynamic:

```
    <select id="selectcountry">
    <option value="1">India</option>
    <option value="2">Ireland</option>
    </select>
    <script>
     var country_name ='India'
     $('#selectcountry').find('option:contains("' + country_name + '")').attr('selected', 'selected');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Effective and efficient way to set selected value in dropdown using your text value

```
 $("#id option").filter(function () {
     //may want to use $.trim in here
     return $(this).text() == customerName.trim();
 }).prop('selected', true);
```