# how to set text of option:selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>

<select id="youSelect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

Now on click of a button I want to set mySelect option:selected value in youSelect So for this I had done this

`$('#youSelect option:selected').text($('#myselect option:selected').text())`

but its not working.Please guide how to solve this.

Comment: U all didn't get my point what I wnat Please got through question ave edited it

Comment: Which jQuery version do you use? I did't get your point. 
Does it mean that you need to select the value in the second `dropdown` which you selected in the first `dropdown`

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
$('#youSelect').val($('#myselect').val());
```

You are matching the values, not the text.

**Edit:** Based on your edited question, you're probably looking at the same situation as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644449/jquery-setting-select-list-selected-based-on-text-failing-strangely)

```
var _mySelectText = $("#myselect option:selected").text();
$("#youSelect option").filter(function () {
    return this.text === _mySelectText;
}).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#youSelect").val("thevalue");
```

just make sure the value in the options tags matches the value in the val method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var myValue = $("#myselect option:selected").text();
  var secondoption = $("#youSelect")[0];


  for (var i = 0, sL = secondoption.length; i < sL; i++) {
    if (secondoption.options[i].text == myValue) {
      secondoption.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GVt8rZswjzZTC13vw98N?p=preview

Comment: U didn't understand what I want is $('#youSelec option:selected').text($('#myselect option:selected').text()) but its not working

Comment: so you want to set the second Option's value based on the text in the first?

Comment: But the text from the first option does not exist as value on the second. Even if I make the plunker, your HTML is wrong

Comment: first option value in second like if I get first option:selected text as mrs so I want youSelect option:selected text is also be mrs  Now u understand

Comment: Updated the answer. So you want two Options to have matched text, though they have different values

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$(selector_to_your_button).on('click',function(){
    $('#youSelect).val($("#myselect").val());
});
```

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, the value of `youSelect` should bet set on click of a button , not on `change` of `myselect`.