# Is it possible to set value for drop down using the display text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm having the select field as below.

```
<select id="mySelect1">
  <option value="-1">select</option>
  <option value="1">Node-Red</option>
  <option value="2">Node</option>
  <option value="2">Node-JS</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** I have the same value for two options.

When I tried below link suggestion it always set the final matching value.

[jQuery: Setting select list 'selected' based on text, failing strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644449/jquery-setting-select-list-selected-based-on-text-failing-strangely)

example: if I tried to set the value for the drop down as "Node" using the below code, it always selects Node-JS in the drop-down.

```
$("#mySelect1 option:contains("Node")").attr("selected", true);
```

So is it possible to set the drop down values using the text(**not with matching value** ) with the same value for many options ?

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Why not set the option values unique and then during processing figure out if they're one and the same?

Comment: Both "Node" and "Node-JS" contain "Node" as part of the value.  It's going to select both, try to select both of them, which will result in the last one being selected.

Answer (score 0):

The `option:contains("Node")` selector will select all the option that contains the word `Node`, there's no selector for the exact same text you need to filter the options in this case :

```js
$("#mySelect1 option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === 'Node';
}).attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect1">
  <option value="-1">select</option>
  <option value="1">Node-Red</option>
  <option value="2">Node</option>
  <option value="2">Node-JS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is almost a straight dup answer from the dup post.  Except this uses attr() vs prop()