# Appending record & Making it "selected"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form which takes info on events.  In addition to the  fields are a couple of  lists which are created by php using values stored in other tables of the db.

If the user wants to add an , I want to take the data from a 'quick form', insert a new record in the appropriate table, then make that record the selected="selected" record in the drop-down list.

What functions should I be using to get this going?  I'm not asking for you to code the whole thing, just looking for a few hints on what should be included so I can learn by doing & put this together on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

- First of all you will use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to capture events for dynamically generated HTML.
- To change select options on some events, have a look at this: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/
- To select an item from select options look at this: [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)