# copy form field values

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to write a code that will copy one set of form values into another. And normally it is done by something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyGroup() {
    if(document.formName.copy[0].checked){
        document.formName.a1.value = document.formName.b1.value;
        document.formName.a2.value = document.formName.b2.value;
        document.formName.a3.value = document.formName.b3.value;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="formName">
    <input type="text" name="a1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="a2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="a3">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="copy" onSelect="copyGroup()"> Copy Group 1
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="b1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="b2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="b3">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

However, I'd like to modify it in such a way that if the checkbox is selected and the the user went back and modified any values in group 1 -- the corresponding fields in group 2 are updated as well.

I think it can be done, but not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery and try something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/nA37d/

Comment: Wow! This is really cool. Is there a way to disable the fields in the second group, when the checkbox in enabled, while still showing the values being copied?

Comment: A bit too fast there. See this updated fiddle insted. http://jsfiddle.net/nA37d/3/

Comment: Thanks! This is great! I made one change, though. Instead of .attr("readonly", true) I put .attr("disabled", "disabled"); Works like a charm.

Comment: Disabled will make your fields gray, while readonly only makes them read only :-)

Comment: Yes, I needed to visually show that they are disabled and that the data is populated from different fields. Readonly makes me feel that something is wrong, since i am able to click in but not able to edit... I guess it's more of a UX issue for me. Now, is there a way to be able to load function on page load?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description

Comment: I think I'm having a difficulty in passing a value from a drop-down to drop-down... Does it work differently? Lemme dig a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/qnrNC/

Comment: OK, I'm making progress. It "almost" works, at least when I select the checkbox. now i just need to make sure drop-down responds like other fields, while the checkbox is selected: http://jsfiddle.net/tYBeq/

Comment: Ah, I was so close! but you beat me to it! :) I missed one input in bind statement...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help:

```
function copyElement(copyFrom, whereToCopy) {
    if(document.formName.copy.checked){
        document.formName.elements[whereToCopy].value = copyFrom.value;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="formName">
    <input type="text" name="a1" onkeypress="copyElement(this, 'b1')">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="a2" onkeypress="copyElement(this, 'b2')">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="a3" onkeypress="copyElement(this, 'b3')">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="copy"> Copy Group 1
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="b1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="b2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="b3">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add onchange event to the elements and call your function.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the onchange-events of each input field and if the checkbox is checked then copy the values, but that would copy lots of data all the time, and as such is not very efficient.

Another way is to use a button instead of a checkbox (a button with the value "Copy to other form" can hardly be misinterpreted, whereas a checkbox is ambigous), and in the onclick-event of the button trigger the copy-code.

Just a note: I would choose to use jQuery for this, and just type $("#formName input").change(function(stuff)); or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can always use one of WYSIWYG form builders.