# Jquery: How to programmatically select an option within a li element

Tags: jquery, select

I want to select an option by text.
Here is my javascript function. I tried two ways but no luck.
Help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
function preselect(selectedText)
{
     //not ok
     $('#item1 .partDesc').val(selectedText);

     //not ok either
     $('#item1 .partDesc option[value='+ selectedText +']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}

<ul id="myUL">
   <li id="item1">
      <select class="partDesc"><option>Front</option><option>Rear</option></select>
      <input type="text" class="itemDesc">
      <img src="images/myimg.jpg" class="itemImg" > 
   </li>
   <li id="item2">
      <select class="partDesc"><option>Front</option><option>Rear</option></select>
      <input type="text" class="itemDesc">
      <img src="images/myimg.jpg" class="itemImg" > 
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Comment: That's why I tried to do $('#item1 option[text='+ selectedText +']').attr('selected', 'selected');

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is the [`:contains()` selector.](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
var myOption = $('#item1 .partDesc option:contains(' + selectedText + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.itemDesc').keyup(function(){
        var defaultSelection = "Front";
        var element = $(this).parents("li").find('.partDesc');
        element.val($(this).val());
        if(element.val()==null){
            element.val(defaultSelection);
        };
    });
});
```