# Setting a SELECT element by text, not value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is relatively easy and straightforward, but I'm having no success figuring it out.

I am trying to set the selected option of a drop down list element using the following code:

```
        if ($(this).attr("tagName") == "SELECT") {

            oldValue = $(this).parent().parent().find('span.displayField').text();
            $(this).val(oldValue).attr("selected", "selected");
            return;
        }
```

But it is not changing the select element at all.  The code is definitely running, and `oldValue` is being populated appropriately.

Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

For clarification, here is the HTML:

```
        <span class="displayField">Pending</span>
        <span class="editField">            
            <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProgramStatusId must be a number." data-val-required="The ProgramStatusId field is required." id="ProgramListViewModels_0__ProgramStatusId" name="ProgramListViewModels[0].ProgramStatusId">
            <option value="1">Pending</option>
            <option value="2">Tabled</option>
            <option value="3">Approved</option>
            <option value="4">Declined</option>
            </select>  
        </span>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select? The element with `$('span.displayField').text()` as the current text?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Comment: @jcm - That is correct.  I have the text of the original choice in that span, and I'd like to revert the drop down list to that choice.  I don't know it's value, only it's text.

Comment: My answer should do exactly that.

Comment: It is, but as the comments notes the answer no longer works after jQuery 1.4.  I didn't see a functonal update to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).val(oldValue)` will set the value of `this` to `oldValue`, and you just wanna find options with that texy.  You want to use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for this.

```
    if ($(this).is('select')) {
        oldValue = $(this).parent().parent().find('span.displayField').text();
        $('option:contains('+oldValue+')', this).attr("selected", "selected");
        return;
    }
```

Or if there are multiple options that contain the text, but are different, try this:

```
    if ($(this).is('select')) {
        oldValue = $(this).parent().parent().find('span.displayField').text();
        $('option', this).filter(function(){
          return this.text === oldValue;
        }).attr("selected", "selected");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This is close, except the value attributes of my options are not the same as the text, so $('option[value="'+oldValue+'"]',this) doesn't actually find anything.

Comment: @Ben: Oops, try this.  I changed `value=` to `:contains(`, this should find what you want.

Comment: This appears to have done the trick!
Thank you also for the $(this).is() syntax.  I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

If I Understand your snippet correctly. I believe what you're trying to do is select the item with the same `text()` as `$('span.displayField')`.

```
if ($(this).attr('tagName') == 'SELECT') {
    // unselect previously selected element first.
    var prev = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', false);

    // select item with text from span.displayField
    var oldText = $(this).parent().parent().find('span.displayField').text();
    var oldOption = $(this).find('option[text="' + oldText + '"]');

    oldOption.attr('selected', true);
}
```

Comment: thank you, the "unselect" portion above was extremely helpful (I hadn't yet considered it).  using "option[text=" did not seem to work, but Rocket's answer above ("option:contains") did work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what is that

```
).parent().parent().
```

if you just want to set select box value selected try these

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('select.foo option:selected').val();    // get the value from a dropdown select
$('select.foo').val();                    // get the value from a dropdown select
```

Comment: `parent()` is a jquery DOM traversal function for getting the direct parent tag of the current element. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: yes i know , but if he give the id of the select box , he can avoid this parent.parent. if there is no duplicate element id . Is it?

Comment: I am traversing up through the DOM in order to get the text that I want to set the select element to.  This is happening in response to a button click and that text represens what I wish to set the select element to, regardless of what the user may have done up to that point.