# Problem using jQuery change function on a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using a simple select element. On selecting a option in the select menu, I want to use jQuery's post method to update the div.

```
<select class="article">
    <option value="title1">title1</option>
    <option value="title2">title2</option>
    <option value="title3">title3</option>
</select>
```

I want to bind the change event to the select element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".article").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

This does not work. I don't see the alert box on changing the select box.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What browser? Have you checked for errors in Firebug or the error console (if you're using Firefox)?

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/pnvxw/.

Comment: Make sure there are *NO* js errors on the page (*due to other scripts*)

Comment: This works for me as well. I think Ish is right to suspect other scripts being at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work fine

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bCB2x/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, have you included jQuery files. Please check that jQuery is included properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

This should give an alert, in case this does not, then jQuery is not working properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('select.foo option:selected').val();    // get the value from a dropdown select
```

More about the subject;

http://api.jquery.com/val/

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

[jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description/496107#496107)

Comment: The same documentation says that `$('select.foo').val();` is equivalent.