# Most efficient way to select all elements with an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's suppose I have a `<select>` element:

```
<select id="foobar" name="foobar" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Foobar 1</option>
    <option value="2">Foobar 2</option>
    <option value="3">Foobar 3</option>
</select>
```

And let's suppose I have an array of values, something like:

```
var optionValues = [2, 3];
```

How can I select the `<option>`s with values 2 and 3 most efficiently?

I'm working with a `<select>` that has thousands of `<option>`s, so doing it manually like this won't work:

```
var optionElements = [];

$("#foobar").children().each(function() {
    if($.inArray($(this).val(), optionValues)) {
        optionElements.push($(this));
    }
}
```

It's just too slow. Is there a way to hand jQuery a list of values for the elements I need to select? Any ideas?

P.S. In case you're wondering, I am in the middle of optimizing my [jQuery PickList widget](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/) which currently [sucks at handling large lists](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/issues/detail?id=6).

Comment: Could you make a fiddle to illustrate the performance issue?

Comment: Also, do you need it to be an array of jQuery objects? I'd use a single jQuery object wrapping all selected elements.

Comment: @Fabrício, the bug report is linked in the question, and as the person who reported the bug stated: the large item list plus all the JS that is running on jsFiddle makes it impractical. He did, however, post a test case. See the bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/issues/detail?id=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank you all for the awesome responses! I'm considering each one, and I will probably do benchmarks before I make a decision.

In the interim, I actually found an "acceptable" solution [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496126/848393) to another question.

Here's what I came up with (the last block, with the custom `filter()` implementation, is where the magic happens):

```
var items = self.sourceList.children(".ui-selected");

var itemIds = [];
items.each(function()
{
    itemIds.push( this.value );
});

self.element.children().filter(function()
{
    return $.inArray(this.value, itemIds) != -1;
}).attr("selected", "selected");
```

I doubt this is as efficient as any of the stuff you guys posted, but it has decreased the "Add" picklist operation time from about 10 seconds to 300ms on a 1500 item list.

Comment: I think you will find the regular expression version (and some of the others) to be very much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered creating a big hashtable at plugin bootstrap? Granted values are unique:

```
var options = {};

$('#foobar').children().each(function(){

    options[this.value] = this;

});
```

This way looking up is straightforward - `options[valueNeeded]`.

EDIT - searching for `optionValues`:

```
var optionValues = [2, 3];

var results = [];

for(i=0; i<optionValues.length;i++){

    results.push[ options[ optionValues[i] ] ];

}
```

Comment: `this.value` is preferred over `$(this).val()` when performance is concerned.

Comment: Not sure but I don't see where you're doing the filtering - apparently you're iterating over all options with `.each` and pushing 'em all into the object.

Comment: I thought as much. Yup looks good now and you can even store the first options caching on an outer scope for future operations.

Comment: Hi moonwave, yeah the hashtable at init was a fleeting thought. I wanted to avoid it if I could. I may go in this direction in the future if the need arises.

Answer (score 2):

This hasn't been profiled so take it with a <strike>grain</strike> shaker of salt:

```
var options = $("some-select").children(),
    toFind = [2, 3],
    values = {},
    selectedValues = [],
    unSelectedValues = [];
// First, make a lookup table of selectable values
// O(1) beats O(n) any day
for (i=0, l=toFind.length; i++; i<l) {
    values[toFind[i]] = true;
}
// Avoid using more complicated constructs like `forEach` where speed is critical
for (i=0, l=options.length; i++; i<l) {
    // Avoid nasty edge cases since we need to support *all* possible values
    // See: http://www.devthought.com/2012/01/18/an-object-is-not-a-hash/
    if (values[options[i]] === true) {
        selectedValues.push(options[i]);
    }
    else {
        unSelectedValues.push(options[i]);
    }
}
```

There is obviously more we can do (like caching the selected and unselected values so we can avoid rebuilding them every time the user moves a value between them) and if we assume that the data is all unique we could even turn the whole thing into three "hashes" - but whatever we do [we should profile it](http://jsperf.com/) and *ensure* that it really is as fast as we *think* it is.

Comment: Upvoted for tip on profiling. I will definitely do that regardless of what I choose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are unique, you can take some shortcuts. For instance, once you have found a value you can stop searching for it by `splice()`ing it off the search array.

This would be the ultimate optimisation, though, taking you from `O(n^2)` all the way down to `O(n log n)`: Sorting.

First, loop through the options and build an array. Basically you just want to convert the NodeList to an Array. Then, `sort` the array with a callback to fetch the option's value. Sort the search array. Now you can loop through the "options" array and look for the current smallest search item.

```
var optsNodeList = document.getElementById('foobar').options,
    optsArray = [], l = optsNodeList.length, i,
    searchArray = [2,3], matches = [], misses = [];
for( i=0; i<l; i++) optsArray[i] = optsNodeList[i];
optsArray.sort(function(a,b) {return a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1;});
searchArray.sort();
while(searchArray[0] && (i = optsArray.shift())) {
    while( i > searchArray[0]) {
        misses.push(searchArray.shift());
    }
    if( i == searchArray[0]) {
        matches.push(i);
        searchArray.shift();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $found = [];
var notFound = [];
var $opt = $('#foobar option');
$.each(optionValues, function(i, v){
    var $this = $opt.filter('[value='+v+']');
    if ($this.length) {
       $elems.push($this)
    } else {
       notFound.push(v);
    } 
})
```

Comment: I'd personally go with this solution, still, an array of jQuery objects isn't very considerate with the memory. I'd revise that if I were the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would give jQuery's [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method a try, something like:

```
var matches = filter(function() {
    // Determine if "this" is a match and return true/false appropriately
});

// Do something with the matches
matches.addClass('foobar');
```

It may not be the fastest solution here, but it is fairly optimized and very very simple without having to keep track of lists and all that jazz. It should be fast enough for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var optionValues = [2, 3],
    elements = [],
    options = document.getElementById('foobar').options;

var i = 0;
do {
    var option = options[i];
    if(optionValues.indexOf(+option.value) != -1) {
        elements.push(option);
    }
} while(i++ < options.length - 1);
```

Comment: This operation may look small and harmless, but it loops through every `optionValues` element for every single `option`. Such a loop is quadratic, otherwise known as "not good".

Answer (score 0):

Let optionValues by an array of indexes to be selected.

```
for(var i = 0; i < optionValues.length; i++) {
  document.forms[0].foobar.options[optionValues[i]].selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select by value, the following should be suitable. It only loops over the options once and doesn't call any other functions, only one built–in method so it should be quick.

```
function selectMultiByValue(el, valuesArr) {

  var opts = el.options;
  var re = new RegExp('^(' + valuesArr.join('|') + ')$');

  // Select options
  for (var i=0, iLen=opts.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opts[i].selected = re.test(opts[i].value);
  } 
}
```

In some browsers, looping over a collection is slow so it may pay to convert the options collection to an array first. But test before doing that, it may not be worth it.

Note that if the select isn't a multiple select, only the option with the last listed value will be selected.

You may need to fiddle with the regular expression if you want to allow various other characters or cases.