# option:selected not working jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery

The following:

```
  $("select option:contains(fish)").attr('selected', true);
```

Works wonderfully in anything below jQuery 1.9, but does not work at all in jQuery 1.9+.  I have been searching for any documentation on any change, but have not found anything.

Any idea how to get this code to work with the new jquery?

Example Here (defaults to jQuery 1.4): http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/TZmEw/

Comment: use `.prop()` in 1.9 and not `.attr()`.

Comment: This may still be somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: You rarely actually want to work with the attribute, in most cases what you really want is the property.

Comment: Thank you!  Wasn't aware of this change, maybe I have had my head in the sand... but, I have a whole bunch of code I need to update now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Prop api instead of attr for jquery 1.9.

```
$("select option:contains(fish)").prop('selected', 'selected');
```

OR

```
 $("select option:contains(fish)").prop('selected', true);
```

Reason : jQuery 1.6 introduced the .prop() method for setting or getting properties on nodes and deprecated the use of .attr() to set properties. However, versions up to 1.9 continued to support using .attr() for specific situations. This behavior in the name of backwards compatibility causes confusion when selectors are used that distinguish between attributes and properties.

Source : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9

Mentioned in Attr Api : **As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.**

Source : http://api.jquery.com/attr/#entry-longdesc

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ The jQuery documentation says nothing about attr being deprecated in favor of prop.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `.attr()` API is not deprecated. Using the `.attr()` API improperly is deprecated, and has been since jQuery 1.6. As of version 1.9, jQuery no longer tries to convert `.attr()` into `.prop()` automatically because it confuses things even worse -- for example when selecting elements. To change the dynamic value of a form element, use `.prop()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select option:contains(fish)").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see [the jQuery documentation on the topic](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-) with respect to 1.9 specifically.  `.attr` vs. `.prop` can be confusing since that I know of there is no specific way to know what "properties" are.  For all intents and purposes, when changing values that the user has the ability to change .. especially boolean values, you should use `.prop`

One exception is an input's value -- you should use `.val` for that.  Similarly, it's probably better to use `.val` to set the `<select>` elements value -- not easy to do in your case, but it would be more accurate.

> jQuery 1.6 introduced the .prop() method for setting or getting properties on nodes and deprecated the use of .attr() to set properties. However, versions up to 1.9 continued to support using .attr() for specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("select option").removeAttr('selected').filter(":contains(fish)").attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery `1.6`, you should be using `prop`:

```
$("select option:contains(fish)").prop('selected', true);
```

In jQuery `1.6.1`, they re-introduced this functionality to the `attr` method, for backwards compatibility (people were complaining). In `1.9` [they removed it again](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-), since this functionality has been deprecated long enough.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't fire an 'onchange' event. Do you know how to make it fire the event?

Comment: @GuyKorland - You have to trigger it yourself: `$("select").find("option:contains(fish)").prop('selected', true).end().change();`

Comment: it doesn't seem like change() really trigger the expected event.