# Cannot get selected value of select with jQuery when the select has been set with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create some cascading dropdowns, I have this I built function which half works:

```
 function CascadeDropDowns(parentClass, childClass, action) {

   var DropDownId = $(parentClass + " option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
     url: "/Terminals_configuration/" + action,
     data: { DropDownId: DropDownId },
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     error: function () {
       alert("An error occurred.");
     },
     success: function (data) {
       var items = "";
       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
           items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
       });
         $(childClass).html(items);
         $(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
     }
   });
  }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".DeviceTypeDDL").change(function () {
        CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups");
        CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
      });
      $(".ConfigGroupDDL").change(function () {
        CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
      });
    });
```

Relevant HTML - Link to jQuery v1.8.2 not included here!

```
<form action="/Terminals_configuration" method="post">    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h2>Configuration settings</h2>
      </legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="DeviceType">Device type</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <select class="DeviceTypeDDL" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DeviceTypeSelectedItem must be a number." id="DeviceTypeSelectedItem" name="DeviceTypeSelectedItem"><option value="8">IT</option>
<option value="9">RS</option>
</select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeviceTypeSelectedItem" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="ConfigGroup">ConfigGroup</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <select class="ConfigGroupDDL" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ConfigGroupSelectedItem must be a number." id="ConfigGroupSelectedItem" name="ConfigGroupSelectedItem"><option value="-1">No value</option>
</select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfigGroupSelectedItem" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="ConfigName">ConfigName</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <select class="ConfigNameDDL" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ConfigNameSelectedItem must be a number." id="ConfigNameSelectedItem" name="ConfigNameSelectedItem"><option value="-1">No value</option>
</select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfigNameSelectedItem" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="ConfigValue">ConfigValue</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter the configuration value" id="ConfigValue" name="ConfigValue" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfigValue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="MergeOrDelete">MergeOrDelete</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <select class="MergeDeleteDDL" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem must be a number." id="MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem" name="MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem"><option value="0">Delete</option>
<option value="1">Merge</option>
</select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>


      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The issue is When the first dropdown is changed i will need to populate the two children. And when the second dropdown is changed I only need to populate the one child.

I thought that by setting `$(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;` then this would make this value selected, so that when the function fires a second time with the child dropdown that has just been populated it would be able to get this value, but it doesn't.

I'm thinking maybe the new  are not available in the DOM at this point but im not sure.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please add your HTML markup too :)

Comment: Done, hopefully you've some help for me

Comment: If you've no interest in answering the question then dont comment at all. Especially when in this instance seeing the HTML is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be, that your second `CascadeDropDowns` function is executed before the first one has finished its execution (since you're doing an AJAX call, which is asynchronous).

One way of making the second function wait for the first one is by utilizing jQuery deferreds:

```
function CascadeDropDowns(parentClass, childClass, action) {

   var completeDeferred = $.Deferred();
   var DropDownId = $(parentClass + " option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
     url: "/Terminals_configuration/" + action,
     data: { DropDownId: DropDownId },
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     error: function () {
       alert("An error occurred.");
     },
     success: function (data) {
       var items = "";
       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
           items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
       });
         $(childClass).html(items);
         $(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
         completeDeferred.resolve();
     }
   });

   return completeDeferred;
}
```

then use the returned deferred:

```
$(".DeviceTypeDDL").change(function () {
    var deferred = CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups");
    deferred.then(function() {
        CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
    })
});
```

An easier way might be to modify the function to accept a callback:

```
function CascadeDropDowns(parentClass, childClass, action, callback) {
   var DropDownId = $(parentClass + " option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
     url: "/Terminals_configuration/" + action,
     data: { DropDownId: DropDownId },
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     error: function () {
       alert("An error occurred.");
     },
     success: function (data) {
       var items = "";
       $.each(data, function (i, item) {
           items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
       });
         $(childClass).html(items);
         $(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
         if (callback) {
             callback();
         }
     }
   });
}
```

then use it like this:

```
$(".DeviceTypeDDL").change(function () {
    var callback = function() {
        CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
    };
    CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups", callback);
});
```

Comment: Thankyou Ill give it a go and let you know.

Comment: The first option didnt work but the callback did. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of the option you need to select, you can just use:

```
$(childClass).val(valOfOption);
```

There are some other options posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Comment: Thanks but the options are data driven so could change. See accepted answer above.