# How to display checked value in Jquery Dropdown List populate from database

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu

How to display ticked/checked data in a JQuery Dropdown list.
Basically my problem is that i want to display back checked value in a jquery dropdown list which is store in the database.

i tried using attr selected in my javascript,something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#<?php echo $bnum; ?>").dropdownchecklist({width: 300});
        //the option value suppose to be dynamic,but for the purpose of this question,
        the value will be someothing like this.
                $("#<?php echo $bnum; ?> option[value='2']").attr("selected", true);

    });
</script>
```

Value for the checked box that i retrive from a sql procedure is something like this:

For room 501: 2

What i currenty trying to do, is when a user clicked on the page. The dropdown checklist is checked with the value retrived from the database

Below this is the code for the rows of room which contains a Jquery for each of the row

```
<select id="<?php print $bnum; ?>" multiple="multiple" name="status[]" >
    <option value="0"></option>
    <?php
    //query drop-down list 
    $sqlakh = "select diet_id,diet_name from bmsdb.diettypes";
    $resultakh = mysql_query($sqlakh);

    while ($rowsakh = mysql_fetch_array($resultakh)) {
        ?>
        <option  value='<?php echo $rowsakh['diet_id'] . '|' . $bnum; ?>'  "selected" : ''>
            <?php echo $rowsakh['diet_name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance, im new in javascript. Can someone guide me on how display back the checked item in the Jquery dropdown list which retrived from the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this question: [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

But if you use php to build the option html, why not set the selected option with php.
Something like this in your loop (just an example!)

```
<?php
  $sel = '';
  if($rowsakh['diet_id'] == $_POST['someVarName'])
  {
    $sel = 'selected';
  }    
  echo '  <option value="' . $rowsakh['diet_id'] . '|' . $bnum . '"' . $sel . '>Audi</option>';
?>
```

I personnaly wouldn't use echo statements in the while loop. I would concatenate it as a long string and finally echo once at the end.