# Jquery selector - text equals - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<select id="myDDL">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">default</option>
    <option value="1">apples</option>
    <option value="2">oranges</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
setFieldValue("myDDL", "apples");

function setFieldValue(field, value)
{
    var val = $("#" + field + " option[text]");
    console.log(val);
    $("#" + field).val(val);
}
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/nnvh7e43/

I would like to select an option within a select field based on its text, i.e.:

```
var val = $("#" + field + " option[text='" + value + "']");
```

However as soon as I add [text] after option the selector seems to select the entire document, whereas $("#" + field + " option"); simply selects all option tags within the select field, as I would expect.

Could you please explain why it does not recognise "[text]" and how I can correct this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find element by text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apples` is text of option and not its value. You need to use `.filter()` function here:

```
 $("#" + field + " option").filter(function(){
       return $(this).text() === value ;
 });
```

Also, You are trying to get the option value by text and then set its 
value to select. You can rather set the selected property of option to true for setting it selected:

```
 $("#" + field + " option").filter(function(){
       return $(this).text() === value ;
 }).prop('selected', true);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xw8sende/)**

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` css selector can only be used on attributes (`href`, `selected`, `value`, `class`, `id`, ...). You can't use it on the content of an html element.

Milind Anantwar solution is the way to go. Use `filter` :

```
 $("#" + field + " option").filter(function(){
     return $(this).text() === value ;
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
function setFieldValue(field, value) {

    // First filter all option by text, then get that option value
    var val = $("#" + field + " option").filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == value;
    }).val();
    console.log(val);

    // Set the option w/ text value here
    $("#" + field).val(val);
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/palash/nnvh7e43/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Selectors like `tagname[attributename]` look for an actual attribute on the `tagname` element. Your `option` elements do not have a `text` attribute. So you need to either give them a `text` attribute or, probably preferable, modify your selector to examine the actual inner text of the element rather than look for an attribute, e.g. with `contains`:

```
var val = $("#" + field + " option:contains(" + value + ")");
```

Comment: will break when option `custard apples`  comes

Comment: Yes was going to say, I intentionally avoided contains because I need an exact match, though i realise I never stated this in the question