# Jquery — how can i change <select> values outside of DOM then inject?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating html in javascript with jquery, which I will then set values and inject into the dom.

See simple example below:

```
var $html = $('<div><select class"target"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></div>');
$html.find('.target').val('2');
$('body').html($html.prop('outerHTML'));
```

However this does not work (it does work for text inputs).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without digging too deep, I noticed in your `select` element, it just says `class"target"` when it should probably say `class="target"`...wondering if that's your issue.

Comment: (Correcting that typo doesn't fix the problem, no.)

Comment: why not just set the value and append the html? or is this just an example with static values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description

Comment: I suggest your issue is this: Settings the value of a `<select>` element with jQuery's `.val()` method doesn't work, while settings the value of an `<input>` will work:

Answer (score 2):

```
var $html = $('<div><select class="target"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></div>');
$html.find('.target').val('2');
$('body').html($html);
```

I think this code should produce the correct output, the output that you are looking for. Rather than adding raw html, I appended an actual jQuery variable in your dom.

Also there was a typo for class name, it should be `class="target"`

Here is the working fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xycmLktu/)

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand what's meant by your code `html($html.prop('outerHTML'))`

If you want let `$html` into document you can create a div

```
$html.appendTo('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a select HTMLElement, the selection is maintained internally in the `selectedIndex` attribute of the element object. Using `$.val()` on a select also maintains this correctly, but when `$.prop('outerHTML')` is used it's lost. When you append elements to the DOM, it's preserved:

```js
var $html = $('<div><select class="target"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></div>');
$html.find('.target').val('2');
$('body').html('').append($html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $html = $('<div><select class="target"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2!</option><option value="3">3</option></select></div>');
$html.find('.target').val(2);
$('body').append($html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```