# get the value of option tag based on text in HTML SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a question. I have a scenario where I need to get value of option tag based on option text.

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Here imagine that I want to get the value "2" based on the supplied text "two". How can we achieve that?

Comment: Have you googled "how to get select value"? "How to get element by text"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - setting the selected value of a select control via its text description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description)

Comment: or this?: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this javascript

Say this what you provided :

```
<select id="test">
<option value="0">zero</option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>

var e = document.getElementById("test");
var actualValue= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```